# Laravel-MongoDB, how order result by relevant

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I use jenssegers/laravel-mongodb. I make scope

```
public function scopeWhereFullText($query, $search)
    {
        return $query->whereRaw(['$text' => ['$search' => $search]],['score'=>['$meta'=>'textScore']]);
    }
```

How I can order By score field like in MongoDB js example:

```
db.products.find({$text:{$search:"SomeText"}},{score:{$meta:'textScore'}}).sort({score:{$meta:'textScore'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the solution without crutch:

```
public function scopeWhereFullText($query, $search)
{
    $query->getQuery()->projections = ['score'=>['$meta'=>'textScore']];

    return $query->whereRaw(['$text' => ['$search' => $search]]);

}
```

and in result

```
$products = Product::whereFullText($request->get('q',''))
                    ->orderBy('score',['$meta'=>'textScore'])->get();

$max = $products->max('score');
$min = $products->min('score');

$products = $products->filter(function($item) use($max,$min){
    return $item->score > ($max+$min)/2;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$results = DB::connection()->collection('_User')->whereRaw(['$text' => ['$search' => 'SEARCH QUERY']])->project(['score'=>['$meta'=>'textScore']])->orderBy('score', ['$meta' => "textScore"])->limit(10)->get();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Looks like a good answer.  It's usually best practice on StackOverflow to include a little explanation of the answer though, not just the code.